# How to see if an environment variable is defined through batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

I am writing a batch script to use an existing environment variable if it exists. If it doesn't, I need to create that environment variable. When the env variable name exists already, the below code runs fine. When the env variable doesn't exist, it just pops up as a flash.

```
set "my_path=%ENV_VARIABLE_NAME%"
IF %my_path%=="" (
   echo no path found
   set "my_path = C:/Users/xyz/"
) ELSE (
   echo path found
)
pause
```

Answer (score 3):

Your main problem is the line

```
IF %my_path%=="" (
```

When the variable is empty, this is parsed as

```
IF =="" (
```

which is incorrect syntax. The parser shows an error message and ends parsing (closing your window when you started it with a double-click).

The proper syntax would be (quoting *both* sides of the comparison):

```
IF "%my_path%" == ""
```

Although I'd prefer @jeb's solution: `IF defined my_path (`

There is another issue in your code:

```
set "my_path = C:/Users/xyz/"
```

sets a variable `%my_path %` to `<space>C:/Users/xyz/` - not what you want. Correct would be:

```
set "my_path=C:\Users\xyz\"
```

(Note: the correct path delimiter in Windows is a backslash, not a slash)

Comment: `Although I'd prefer @jeb's solution` - I prefer your answer, it's much more extensive :-)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is:

```
IF defined my_path
```

See also the help `IF /?`

Answer (score 1):

This is the mechanism I'd use to perform the task you've provided in your code.

```batch-file
@If Not Defined ENV_VARIABLE_NAME (
    Echo No path found.
    Set "my_path=C:\Users\xyz"
) Else (
    Echo Path found.
    Set "my_path=%ENV_VARIABLE_NAME%"
)
```

Or as a single line without the unnecessary `echo`ing:

```batch-file
@If Not Defined ENV_VARIABLE_NAME (Set "my_path=C:\Users\xyz") Else Set "my_path=%ENV_VARIABLE_NAME%"
```

Alternatively:

```batch-file
@If Defined ENV_VARIABLE_NAME (
    Echo Path found.
    Set "my_path=%ENV_VARIABLE_NAME%"
) Else (
    Echo No path found.
    Set "my_path=C:\Users\xyz"
)
```

Or as a single line without the unnecessary `echo`ing:

```batch-file
@If Defined ENV_VARIABLE_NAME (Set "my_path=%ENV_VARIABLE_NAME%") Else Set "my_path=C:\Users\xyz"
```

Answer (score 0):

Of some small note, using `IF Defined` is not *just* a different way to check the variable, it is generally a preferable method as it provides two enhanced features:

As it It does not explcitly check the contents of the variable, but instead looks up the name when the command is run.

This means that if the contents of the variable were such that they would have been troublesome to correctly escape it provides no issue..

This also means that the command can be used inside for loops or parenthesis whether or not you use delayed expansion because it's lookup is strictly a command, and so must be done at execution instead of pre-execution

You can also replicate this functionality by using `SET | FIND "MYVar="` as again this requires the set command to be run and check the state of the environment at execution, instead of pre-execution.